# How do I deserialize this JSON array (C#)

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I am struggling with a subject that has a lot of variants, but I can't seem to find one that works for me, and I think it's because of the way that my JSON array is.
I'm not an expert in C# or JSON, but I already manage to "almost" get this to work. I need to get hand with the class that the JSON will deserialize to.

When I run the code I dont get an error, just a nulls in the xKisokData var.

The JSON data that I am getting. Their are these two different ones.

```
"{\"Event\": \"sConnection\",\"data[device]\": \"fb16f550-2ef1-11e5-afe9-ff37129acbf4\",\"data[mode]\": \"customer\",\"data[starttime]\": \"2015-07-22T16:07:42.030Z\",\"data[endtime]\": \"\"}"
"{\"Event\": \"Log\",\"data[id]\": \"2015-07-22T16:07:23.063Z\",\"data[messages][0][source]\": \"server\",\"data[messages][0][message]\": \"Server is listening on port 1553\"}"
```

The code I have so far:

```
// Read in our Stream into a string...
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(JSONdataStream);
string JSONdata = reader.ReadToEnd();

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
wsKisokData[] xKisokData = jss.Deserialize<wsKisokData[]>(JSONdata);
```

My Class:

```
namespace JSONWebService
{

    [DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    public class KisokEvent
    {
        public string eventTrigger { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    public class KisokData
    {
        public string data { get; set; }

    }

    [DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    public class wsKisokData
    {
        public KisokEvent KDEvent { get; set; }
        public List<KisokData> KDData { get; set; }

    }

}
```

I am sure that I don't understand the Deserialize process. Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:**
I put the JSON in the top part right from the debugger, here is the strings.

```
{
    "Event": "sConnection",
    "data[device]": "fb16f550-2ef1-11e5-afe9-ff37129acbf4",
    "data[mode]": "customer",
    "data[starttime]": "2015-07-22T16:07:42.030Z",
    "data[endtime]": ""
}

{
    "Event": "Log",
    "data[id]": "2015-07-22T16:07:23.063Z",
    "data[messages][0][source]": "server",
    "data[messages][0][message]": "Server is listening on port 1553"
}
```

Comment: Is all the quoting in the "JSON" samples because you copied them from the VS debugger?

Comment: One possibility is that the properties in your JSON objects appear to be `Event` and `Data`.  The properties on your object is `KDEvent` and `KDData`.  What happens if you change the properties on your .NET object to match?

Comment: This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253633/deserialize-json-when-names-have-brackets-and-parenthesis

Comment: Nice handle @dustmouse but that one didn't work because of when you define the class, "data[id]" c# complains that you are trying to creating an array. Thank you anyway.

Comment: The two JSON examples you show are of objects (outer delimiters are `{}`) rather than arrays (which would have outer delimiters of `[]`).  Why are you trying to deserialize as an array?

Comment: There is no way to automatically deserialise these strings, you would need to build a custom converter.

Comment: @DavidG - To be completely honest, I thought that was what it was called. I am struggling with how to go about working with this JSON stream. I so wish I could FIX the string that I am getting, but that is out of my hands. At this point I am not sure what to do other than .Replace() on the input string before I deserialise it. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would HIGHLY recommend using the json.net package off nuget instead.
You can generate template classes (models) for it by pasting the json into http://json2csharp.com/

Then use said models to convert the json into a c# object (deserializing) by doing a

```
var jsonStructure = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<model>(json)
```

And query as if it was just a standard object

```
foreach (var x in jsonStructure.KDData)
{
    doAction(x.data);
}
// for example
```

Comment: Kaelan Fouwels - I used the json strings from above, not the ones in quotes, and the json2CSparp returned errors, __invalid_name__data[...]_Nope that didn't work, but thanks for the suggestions.